# seeking feedback for course from learners

Tags: feedback, courses

Our users view courses by launching them from our Learning Management System (LMS). It opens in a new window. We call it course player.

The window has main sections as shown:

[image]

The course tree is to navigate through the course. And the course display area is the content.

The course duration usually ranges 2 hours to 24 hours.

The users are mainly engineers who can be designers, reviewers, program managers. Also, engineering students, who just joined the organization or under some academic program get access to our content within the university.

**Problem**

We do not have any mechanism to capture the feedback from the users while they are taking the course or when they are done with the course. To capture the feedback in a subtle way is what I am trying to work.

My objective is

1. **When** and **how often** to ask for feedback during the course. With this, I mean what is the most appropriate time to ask for feedback. Certainly, at the end is an ideal opportunity to throw feedback question. But in our scenario, sometimes users take the course for a specific portion of the course and close the player.

**Proposal**

My Idea is shown below, with red circles as triggers causing the pop-up of feedback panel. That is when the user

- has made a progress of x% of course (is it a good idea?)
- closes the player (Wouldn't it be intimidating next time the user closes the player?)
- clicks the button provided just below tree (it's the most direct and loud way of asking feedback. I am not happy with this, but would like to see your opinion)

[image]
Consider an example, the course is 4 hours, and the user has spent already 1 hour browsing the course. And has made a progress of 30% completion. Is it time to ask for feedback?

2. How many questions to ask the users. My proposal is to keep the feedback as Subjective and try to assess their emotional level in terms of asking about the experience by rating, as shown below. I am keeping it very minimalistic coz number of questions may annoy users. A better way would be to collect detailed feedback via a survey asking multiple questions.

[image]

Any other question that can be useful.

Comment: Is the question not clear enough?

Answer (score 1):

My preference would be to let the user drive it. Put a link in an appropriate place called "How are you getting on?" Which launches your feedback module, this way users do not feel harassed in the same we try an gather feedback from website visitors.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should ask for feedback on completion of nth sub segments like after completing 5 sessions. this will give user a small break from the activity and will not bother them in their learning process.

and according to my suggestion, you should ask one question each time - can go for maximum 2 questions.

Comment: Ok, I think its good idea, after 5 sessions, triggering a feedback panel makes sense.